# vite hmr watch log format

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm working on a Nuxt3 project, which uses Vite as a default bundler.

Its HMR was working very fine till I just found out that the whole app is restarting every time there is any change, the console is showing

> ✔ Vite server hmr 9 files in 21.731ms

I mean I obviously changed only one file.
Is there any way to check which 9 files were changed?
Maybe config for logging format?

I tried looking in vite source code and docs, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Isn't it showing the edited files when you change one of them by default? Here is a way I think: https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#handlehotupdate Not sure how to use that one tho.

Comment: @kissu I just found out it might be nuxt3 rc14 problem. After downgrading nuxt to rc12, HMR works just fine

Comment: The latest is RC13: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/releases Glad it works tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP fixed the issue by downgrading to Nuxt RC12.
Probably a regression, there will probably be a changelog note on the next release: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/releases